# how to get the maximum of a column in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i want to know how to get the maximum of these column during the given date parameter these sub query gives the maximum of the whole column not during the date parameter

```
                     SELECT RELEASE_NUM
              FROM XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES
             WHERE RELEASE_ID =
                      (SELECT MAX (RELEASE_ID)
                         FROM XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES
                        WHERE XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES.PO_HEADER_ID =
                                 xxr.PO_HEADER_ID
                  AND TRUNC (RELEASE_date) >= 
                         NVL (:FROM_DATE, TRUNC (RELEASE_date))
                  AND TRUNC (RELEASE_date) <=
                         NVL (:TO_DATE1, TRUNC (RELEASE_date)))
```

Comment: you should add some sample data and desire result

Comment: where is the "given date parameter " in this snippet? If you want us to help you need to provide all the relevant details. A small complete test case is preferable.

Comment: You have not defined the `xxr` alias. I'm assuming it is the outer query so the inner query is a correlated sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

If I've got the logic you are using correct, then something like this:

```
SELECT RELEASE_NUM
FROM   (
  SELECT RELEASE_NUM,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY PO_HEADER_ID
                       ORDER BY     RELEASE_ID DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES
  WHERE  ( :from_date IS NULL OR :from_date <= TRUNC (RELEASE_date) )
  AND    ( :to_date   IS NULL OR :to_date   >= TRUNC (RELEASE_date) )
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

This will get all the rows with the highest `RELEASE_ID` for each `PO_HEADER_ID`. If you only want a single highest row then change `RANK` for `ROW_NUMBER`.

If you just want a single value for all the rows (independent of `PO_HEADER_ID`) then:

```
SELECT MAX( RELEASE_NUM ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY RELEASE_ID ) AS RELESE_NUM
FROM   XXEXTRACT.XXNATGAS_REALSES
WHERE  ( :from_date IS NULL OR :from_date <= TRUNC (RELEASE_date) )
AND    ( :to_date   IS NULL OR :to_date   >= TRUNC (RELEASE_date) )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i trying your query it still dosnt get the right answer  as it get number 2 as the first record and 10 in the second record !! and when i put these query in the main query it gives me an error   "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" so please help me !

Comment: @Tarek What first record? What second record? Where did 2 and 10 come from? What main query? So, please help us by providing a [MCVE] with all the relevant details.